# Ionic - Error generating tabs with "ionic generate tabs"

Tags: angular, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, ionic3

It's my first question. 
I think that my problem is simple, but i've tried to search for an answer and I didn't find it.

I have an error with ionic.

When I use the commands `ionic start myApp blank` and `ionic generate tabs` this error appears in command prompt:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

My Ionic info:

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.0.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3

System:

Node       : v8.1.4
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.3
```

I Hope someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: When you do ionic generate tabs have you changed directory into myApp? If you did, is there more of a stack track than just the message you can post?

Comment: There also seems to be something similar to do with npm install ios-sim over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350505/error-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-when-building-ios-cordova But that would be bad news if you are using Windows, because I doubt ios-sim works on anything other than a Mac.. Have not tried that on Windows machine ...but remember ready how Ionic on Windows was awkward...

Comment: I didn't change the directory.
I'm using Windows and I saw the question about ios-sim and installed it, but it didn't solve my problem.
The windows version must be awkward yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ionic start myApp
```

Then choose tabs from the options that you see on the CLI