# Cordova Reading build config file error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova (7.0.1) and after I'm executing

```
cordova run ios "--target=iPhone-7, 10.3"
```

I'm getting error

```
MAC:folder user$ cordova run ios "--target=iPhone-7, 10.3"          
Reading build config file: Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

However, after I'm executing

```
cordova run ios "--target=iPhone-7, 10.3"
```

Everything works just fine. 'Verbose' doesn't help really.

I thought that the issue is connected with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350505/error-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-when-building-ios-cordova), so I tried to do

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/
sudo npm install -g ios-sim@latest
```

But **no luck**.

Any ideas why it doesn't work if I specify iOS version and how to fix it?
Do I need to put a 'name' property somewhere or it's just a bug?

```
Node              : 8.1.4
npm               : 5.4.1 
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
ios-sim           : 6.0.0 
OS                : 10.12.6
Xcode             : 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is my issue: [issues.apache.org: cordova emulate ios with --target throws undefined error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12830)
Guys from Apache are saying that it was fixed in cordova-ios@4.5.0

So this solved my issue

```
npm i -g cordova-ios@latest
```

However is going to do that - please make sure do it not only for global, but for local project too. i.e.

```
npm i cordova-ios@latest
```

I hope it helps.